# AJAX Y PHP ERROR EN POST

Tags: php, ajax

HOLA TENGO EL SIGUIENTE AJAX:

```
function test(id){
    console.log(id);   //ACA RECIBO EL ID CORRECTAMENTE !!!!
    // var fdp = new FormData();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '../ajax/actualizarEstado_ajax.php',
        type: "POST",
        // data: fdp,
        data:  {id_acta : id}, // ACA LE PASO EL ID 
        success: function (data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('ERROR.');
        },
        cache: true,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        async: true,
    }); 
    console.log('Petición AJAX enviada.');
}
```

CUANDO HAGO UN VAR_DUMP() EN LA URL DONDE VA EL AJAX, ME IMPRIME UN ARRAY VACIO.

```
$parametros = [];
var_dump($_POST);
die();
```

lo extrano es que , el console.log('Petición AJAX enviada.'); me lo imprime primero, y luego el var_dump del php.

Como puedo recibir ese ID correctamente???

Comment: te recomiendo que para probar si recibiste bien ese id no lo hagas con var_dump, intenta hacer un `return echo $_POST`, y dentro den la funcion `success` de tu peticion ajax en la parte donde haces `console.log(data)` te mostrara lo que realmente enviaste.

Comment: ¿Al decir: *CUANDO HAGO UN VAR_DUMP() EN LA URL DONDE VA EL AJAX, ME IMPRIME UN ARRAY VACIO* te refieres a que vas al navegador y pones esa URL y allí  ves el array vacío? Si es así, es lo lógico, porque en ese caso los datos no estarían siendo enviados. En Ajax de jQuery los datos se pasan en el parámetro `data` y para ver la respuesta del servidor debes revisar la consola del navegador, ahí deberías ver el resultado de `console.log(data);` que tienes en el `success`. En cuanto a que ves `Petición AJAX enviada.` primero, es normal, porque las peticiones Ajax son asíncronas ...

Comment: ... Significa que en Ajax (y en Javascript por lo general) muchas cosas no ocurren de forma secuencial, una detrás de otra, sino que varias cosas ocurren en paralelo. Es decir, mientras la petición Ajax se envía al servidor, éste la procesa y devuelve una respuesta, otras cosas siguen ocurriendo en paralelo y el código sigue su curso. No esperes que ocurrirá una cosa y luego otra, no, no funciona así.